# Error when trying to delete record on deactivate

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a record that when deactivated I want a plugin to automatically delete the record. So I have my code set to the SetStateDynamically event and it all works up to the point where I actually get the service to delete the record, where I get "An unexpected error occurred".

My code is below, can anyone see what the problem might be, or be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks

```
private void MarkForDeleteDeactivatedRole(EntityReference entity)
    {
        Entity role = Service.Retrieve("sb_contactsecurityrole", entity.Id, new ColumnSet(true));

        OptionSetValue statusValue = (OptionSetValue)role["statecode"];

        if (statusValue.Value == 1)
        {                
            Service.Delete(entity.LogicalName, entity.Id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual error? If you check the logs or attach the debugger you will be a more specific message. Also how is your plugin registered (pre/post, etc)?

Comment: You should provide the full Execute() method to begin with. Also, try changing the second method line to `... = (OptionSetValue)role.Attributes["statecode"];`

Comment: Have you tried to do it via Workflow?

Comment: I have found another way of doing it using a mixture of workflows and plugins. It appears that it doesn't seem to like deleting a record when you are directly editing it or on it, as Boone had said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the same.  I don't think the CRM event pipeline supports a record being deleted while it is working on that object.  The best you're probably going to be able to do is register your plug-in asynchronously, so the error (which you can't catch, because it is in the CRM event pipeline internals) doesn't bubble to the UI (and you're outside of the transaction).

Comment: This looks like it is the problem, I've found a way to get round it using a mixture of solutions. I'll remember the async idea if I come across anything like this again. Thanks